# Can't open page with OpenUri because of an EOFError

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, open-uri

I'm trying to load a page to parse with Nokogiri. I have:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://market.yandex.ru/product/10791229/spec"))
```

as shown in Nokogiri's tutorial.

I get an error:

```
.../ruby/2.2.0/openssl/buffering.rb:182:in `sysread_nonblock': end of file reached (EOFError)
```

But requesting `https://google.com` or `https://yandex.ru` is fine. Getting that URL using curl works also.

Thinking that I was being blocked because of the "User-Agent" I tried to add `"User-Agent" => specification` to `open` with Mozilla stuff, but still got an error.

Comment: I tried it for Ruby 2.1.1p76 it works fine.

Comment: Your code works without problems with Ruby 2.2.3. What version of Ruby are you using?

Comment: I'm using ruby 2.2.3p173 
So, it really can be that the market.yandex.ru blocking me?